# "Invited them for lunch" vs "invited them to lunch?"

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct form?

Example sentence:

> He explained that his professor had invited his lab **for/to** lunch.

Comment: Neither is "incorrect". Both forms are idiomatic in English. An Ngram devotee might be inspired share an incantation that reveals which is used more frequently.

Comment: Note: not a duplicate of the cited question. Read it carefully.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: I'm afraid I don't see whatever distinction you did; they appear to be excellent duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms

> invite **to** lunch
>   invite **for** lunch

are used and are understandable.  But beware of cannibals if they say

> We'd like to *have* you over **for** lunch.